# When can we allow a CTX segment to be part of 999 Acknowledgement

Tags: x12, hipaa

I need to understand when can we allow a CTX segment to be part of 005010X231-999 Acknowledgement. What I see is an error occured for a required data element. In this case can the CTX be shown to represent the error?
Or will we show the CTX segment only when the data element has a "situational" marked on it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be referencing your trading partners MIG (Message Implementation Guide) for information on the specific segments you can use and their conditions.